# C - Scanf not getting correct info

Tags: c

Why is it when I run my code I get this result:

```
Name: Zeref
Age: 20
Float: 20.11
-----
Name: Zeref
Age: 1072324272
Dec: 0.000000
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char name[524288];
    int age[524288];
    float dec[524288];

    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Age: ");
    scanf("%d", age);
    printf("Float: ");
    scanf("%f", dec);

    printf("-----\n");

    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", age);
    printf("Dec: %f\n", dec);

    return 0;
}
```

it isn't taking in what I say correctly, why?

I want it to print out exactly what I write but using age as an int, dec as a float and name as a string. Only name works

Comment: 524288 is a really unusual buffer length to use here. Usually it's best to stick with 1024 or 4096 as a "good enough" buffer while being aware you have severe buffer overun bugs if you use things like `scanf`. I know names can be long, but a half megabyte name is unheard of.

Comment: @tadman yeahhh, I am not too sure with that kind of thing, I am not use to typing in buff sizes

Comment: If you're going to have a default buffer length it's worth having a constant in C that explains what you're doing, like `#define BUFFER_SIZE 524288` or whatever size you want. That way if you change your mind you can adjust later, plus you can do any safety tests in a consistent manner.

Comment: It's worth turning on compiler warnings (e.g. `-Wall`) to see if the compiler has any grievances with your code it's not telling you about. Many compilers check `printf` arguments but only if you ask them to.

Comment: Using an array for `age` and `dec` suggests you want to read more than one such records of persons?

Comment: Why do you create arrays if you want to read only single values? You could do as well: `int age; scanf("%d", &age);` Curious: What's the meaning of age being -7? If negative ages are meaningless, I'd prefer using unsigned int for (requires format specifier `%u`).

Comment: "it isn't taking in what I say correctly, why?" --> Good compilers, when their warnings are fully enabled, will provide info to solve this.  Save time, enable all warnings.

Comment: @Aconcagua *If negative ages are meaningless, I'd prefer using unsigned int for (requires format specifier `%u`)* Doing so `scanf()` will happily read negative values, report `1` and give you garbage: "u
Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the strtoul function with the value 10 for the base argument."

Comment: @Swordfish 'garbage' is going too far, behaviour is well defined. We couldn't distinguish between large values and negative ones, though, so we might need to check for `value < INT_MAX`, thus discarding both negative and large values? Advantage of not having to check for < 0 gone... Hm, I can remember once having safely used unsigned for not accepting negative values (*long, long* ago), when did this change (I'm absolutely not in favour of...)? Or was the compiler of those days not conforming the standard even then?

Comment: @Swordfish Anyway, I stay with: ***If*** negative values are meaningless for a specific purpose, ***then*** a signed data type is not the appropriate one...

Comment: *when did this change (I'm absolutely not in favour of...)? Or was the compiler of those days not conforming the standard even then?* – I cited C99+TR3 for the behaviour of `%u`. `strtoul`: *If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from the conversion is negated (in the return type).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just printing the address of the array age as a decimal integer (actually it introduces undefined behavior);

```
printf("Age: %d\n", age);
```

Try this

```
printf("Age: %d\n", age[0]);
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I will accept the answer when the system allows me

Comment: @cleblanc For the sake of completeness you maybe want to add something about the use of `"%s"` with `scanf()` and error checking.

Comment: could've fixed `dec` for him as well